# Linux bash Timer

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, while-loop

Ok, stupid newbie question here.  I thought I was making a countdown timer.  This is supposed to count down from 5 and once it is at 0 then execute the echo "time is up clown" then end.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
seconds=5
date1=$((`date +%s` + $seconds)); 
while [ "$date1" -ne `date +%s` ]; do 
  if (!$date1 -lt ((`date +%s` + $seconds)+1)); then
     echo "time is up clown";
  break;
  fi;
  echo -ne "$(date -u --date @$(($date1 - `date +%s` )) +%H:%M:%S)\r";
done
```

Comment: What's wrong with "sleep 5; echo time is up"? :)

Comment: [sleep(1)](http://www.nxmnpg.com/1/sleep).

Comment: Well, for one, the stated intent is to `echo "time is up clown"`, but you actually have `echo "time is up bitch"`.  Or is that not what you were asking after?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
SECS=5
while [[ 0 -ne $SECS ]]; do
    echo "$SECS.."
    sleep 1
    SECS=$[$SECS-1]
done
echo "Time is up, clown."
```

Comment: I tried moving the echo command to after the done statement, but the script stops at done and then does not execute the echo

Comment: never mind.  I had it all along.  Problem was that I was testing it at the prompt and not executing the script as it would normal be executed.  SO your answer was still correct.  Thanks for verifying

Comment: Happy to have helped.