# best way to get the result of `$?` for telnet connections

Tags: bash, process, telnet, kill, pid

I want to telnet some ips and I want to get the result of `$?` immediately:
SO I tried:

```
while read ip; do
    telnet $ip 1>/dev/null 2>&1
    pkill $!
    if [ "$?" -eq "1" ]; then
       echo $ip >> host-ok
    fi
done < file
```

But this is not a good idea because when a telnet connection can't be established it doesn't work. and always the out put of $? would be correct.

I want to be sure telnet is going to be established and then kill the process. So if telnet is established after that I want to echo `$ip` to a file.

Any other solutions are welcome

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean? no I don't use `expect` command becase maybe it has anything as login auth. if you telnet to correcy host then cntrl +c it immediately and wrong host then echo $? you can understand the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fastest and the most reliable solution in the eyes of me:

```
LIST=$1
while read ip;do
    echo "exit" | nc "$ip" 23 -w 5
    if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
        echo "$ip" >> host-ok
    fi
done < $LIST
```

Using `nc` rather than `telnet` is faster.

Answer (score 2):

The code as written doesn't work because the `telnet` command is not [backgrounded](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) - `pkill $!` will *always* fail, because process `$!` no longer exists when you reach that line. You need to append an ampersand `&` at the end of the line to do that. You also need a *timeout* before killing the process, otherwise it won't have time to try to connect before stopping it. `sleep 1` (or 5, or 60, depending on your use case) should take care of that.

You also want to use `kill` rather than `pkill`.

An alternative method which is probably much more robust is to avoid the killing altogether, and simply try to connect and quit immediately (similar to [@PeteyT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23977669/96588)):

```
while read ip; do
    printf '%bquit\n' '\035' | telnet "$ip" 1>/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
       echo "$ip" >> host-ok
    fi
done < file
```

That should use the `telnet` default timeout (I don't know how long that is). If you want a configurable timeout you could try [`netcat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128011/how-do-i-reduce-timeout-on-unix-telnet-on-connection).

Comment: Thank you @l0b0. could you possibly show me how? because doesn't work but logicaly is true

Comment: the previous one was correct. but now: If a telnet connection can't be established it writes: `trying x.x.x.x ... `  If we could send `cntrl + c` it would be better I think

Comment: Why? Most applications handle [SIGTERM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_%28command%29) and SIGINT identically.

Comment: Thank you. How do you see `echo "exit" | nc x.x.x.x 23 -w 3`? if I can telnet it exits and $?=0 if I can't telnet after 3s it exits and $?=1

Comment: Try it and see how it goes.

Comment: `nc` idea was the fastest and most reliable solution in the eyes of me

Answer (score 1):

```
 while read ip; do
   printf '%bquit\n' '\035' | telnet $ip 1>/dev/null 2>&1
   kill $!
   if [ $? -eq "1" ]; then
     echo $ip >> host-ok
   fi
 done < file
```

Comment: Is it correct? ` pkill 035'$!` I think it is missing sth

Comment: that was a typo. point is. all i did was show you how to send the escape sequence '^[' to telnet.

Comment: Thank you. but I have IP when I telnet it the result is `Trying x.x.x.x ...`. how can I discard waiting to these issues

Comment: @MortezaLSC this may be something for you to read? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424985/linux-bash-timer